# How to prevent users to access admin page with user session_destroy

Tags: php, authentication, session

I want to prevent logged in users from accessing admin page with their session when they are logged in.
they should only be able to log in only with username 'admin'.

```
   session_start(); 

   if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
      $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
      header('location: login.php');
   }

   if (isset($_SESSION['username']) != 'admin') {
      session_destroy();
      unset($_SESSION['username']);
      header("location: login.php");
   }

   if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
      session_destroy();
      unset($_SESSION['username']);
      header("location: login.php");
   }
```

Comment: All I can see is that there shouldn't be any output before header, and you are doing just that, given what is posted. Then you have a missing quote in the `'admin` < right there. Was that just a bad paste? If not, then there's the problem. Enable error reporting.

Comment: I fixed the missing quote thinking it was just a paste/copywriting eror.

Comment: You should however include a question in your SO post. We don't know where your problem is and you only described what you want to achieve, but not what your code actually does or where it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   if($_SESSION['username'] !== 'admin'){
     session_destroy();
     unset($_SESSION['username']);
     header("location: login.php");
   }

} else {
   $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
   header('location: login.php');
}
```

the `isset` function would return a boolean value and must not be checked against string.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 86400, '/');
}
session_destroy();
header("location: login.php");
exit();
```

`session_destroy()` is not enough. you should expire cookie too.

and always use `exit();` after `header('location=...');`

Comment: Using exit() after sending a location header is only useful if you write bad code in the first place. Simply don't write any code after the location header is sent (in the same execution branch)